# How to write just an # before some rows in a text file?

Tags: c#

I have a text file who are like this :

```
Rows
...
product.people
product.people_good
product.people_bad
product.boy
#product.me

...
Rows
```

I want to put # before `product.` and the file to be :

```
Rows
...
#product.people
#product.people_good
#product.people_bad
#product.boy
#product.me
...
Rows
```

For this I use next code :

```
string installerfilename = pathTemp + fileArr1;
 string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
 var linInst = File.ReadLines(pathTemp + fileArr1).ToArray();
 foreach (var txt in linInst)
 {
     if (txt.Contains("#product="))
      {              
          installertext = installertext.Replace("#product=", "product=");
      }
     else if (txt.Contains("product.") && (!txt.StartsWith("#")))
      {
        installertext = installertext.Replace(txt, "#" + txt);
      }
       File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);
 }
```

But this code do the next thing:

```
Rows
...
#product.people
##product.people_good
##product.people_bad
#product.boy
#product.me
...
Rows
```

Someone can explain me way ? And how I can write just one # before that rows?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because the code in the question makes it really unclear what's going on. What's `installertext` vs `txt`? What's `linInst`? Do you really want to overwrite the whole file on every iteration? A short but *complete* example would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: You are doing `File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);` for every line. Are you sure that there is no invisible character before `#`. Maybe you should trim it first.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the problem is: if I have an head, in this exemple: "#product.people" the next rows who contains .people_text will have in front two #

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my post, you need more details ?

Comment: Well it's still not a short but complete example - it's not clear why you're reading the same file twice, either.

Comment: please let details ... I don't know way I read twice ... but I think not that it's the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you're reading the same text file twice - ones as individual lines and once as a whole thing. You're then rewriting a file as many times as you have lines. This is all broken. I suspect you simply want:

```
// Note name changes to satisfy .NET conventions
// Note: If pathTemp is a directory, you should use Path.Combine
string installerFileName = pathTemp + fileArr1;
var installerLines = File.ReadLines(installerFileName)
                            .Select(line => line.StartsWith("product=") ? "#" + line : line)
                            .ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(installerFileName, installerLines);
```

If you were writing to a different file than the one you were reading from, you wouldn't need the `ToList` call.

Comment: Here is me code : " CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
            if ((cb.Checked) && (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count))
            {

                if (fileArr1.Equals("installer_input.txt"))
                {
                   string installerLines = File.ReadLines(installerfilename)
                           .Select(line => line.StartsWith("product." ? "#" + line : line)
                           .ToList());
                    File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, installerLines);
                }
            }"

Comment: and I have the next error : "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to bool

Comment: `.Select(line => line.StartsWith("product=" ? "#" + line : line)` should be `.Select(line => line.StartsWith("product=") ? "#" + line : line)`. Missing one parenthesis.

Comment: @user: Gah... Another typo. Try again. But if it doesn't work, please be more specific about where the issue is.

Comment: @user: One question per post, please. Try it yourself, and ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can split by `product`, and then concatenate it to a new string :

```
        // string installerFileText = File.ReadAllText(installerFileName);
        string installerFileText = @"
        Rows
        ...
        product.people
        product.people_good
        product.people_bad
        product.boy
        ...
        Rows";

        string[] lines = installerFileText.Split(new string[] { "product." }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            sb.Append(((i > 0 && i < lines.Length) ? "#product." : "") + lines[i]);

        // File.WriteAllText(installerFileName, sb.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
        Rows
        ...
        #product.people
        #product.people_good
        #product.people_bad
        #product.boy
        ...
        Rows";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
else if (txt.Contains("product.") && (!txt.StartsWith("#")))
{
    installertext = installertext.Replace(txt, "#" + txt);
}
```

Why don't your replace the "!txt.StartsWith("#")" by a "!txt.Contains("#")" ?

Think that would do the trick !

Comment: As you can see I have in file others rows who I don't want to be changed

Comment: This would only change the "product" lines with doesn't contains a "#"

Comment: the rows who I mentioned in my post are important because if I have product.people and after that I have others rows who are like produst.people_text in front of that rows write two of #

Comment: As Jon Skeet told you, we need to get more infos in order to help you then... Installertext, txt, linInst... How did you get all those data ? What do they contains ?